# Take pictures from a service while camera is in use by ARCore

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-camera2

I am playing with the [Android HelloAR example](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/quickstart). Being an AR app, the rear camera is opened and the captured video is presented on-screen to the user.

I want to, from a service, take pictures at some set interval (e.g. 30fps). I don't want video and I don't want the user to have to do anything (e.g. press a button). Further, I do not want to have to do anything other than start/stop the service from the HelloAR app. The service must be totally self-contained so that it will work in a library that I can import into other Android-based AR apps.

Is it possible for my HelloAR app and a service to both have access to the camera simultaneously? If not, is there another way to take a picture or grab a raw frame from the existing/open camera?

Answer (score 0):

To open the front camera:

```
Set<Session.Feature> features  = new HashSet<Session.Feature>();
features.add(Session.Feature.FRONT_CAMERA);
Session = new Session(this,features);
```

To capture the image from Frame in `onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)` method you can do:

```
Frame frame = session.update();
frame.acquireCameraImage();
```

Comment: Thanks - how about when ARCore is not being used? Is it still possible?

Comment: Also, where is `onDrawFrame(GL10 gl` from? I want to hook into a camera that is already in use in some activity, but I want to hook from a service.

Comment: It is in HelloArActivity

Comment: please see this https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/camera-sharing

Comment: Yeh, but the camera-sharing example does not demonstrate how the camera can be accessed simultaneously by two separate services/activities. It only shows how to switch between AR mode and non AR mode. I have a library that I have created and that library has a service and that service needs to take a picture.

Comment: Have you tried putting the current session on hold and releasing the camera

Comment: also can you not pass the frame  obtained to the service class and  do your work

Comment: Hmm, but that would mean that the Hello AR app will stop using the camera. I want the Hello AR app to continue to operate as normal. I want to take a photo from a service without influencing the Hello AR app.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219504/discussion-between-pookie-and-aryan-agarwal).

Comment: why will it interrupt the application when you are passing just the frame , you are not dealing with camera in your service , service are meant for background work and not stopping current activity